# On a proof of a binomial coefficient identity

Tags: combinatorics

In his *Integers, polynomials, and rings: a course in algebra*, Ronald Irving presents the following "alternating sum" identity (**Theorem 8.2** (3), p. 118):

$$
{n \choose 0} - {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} - \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} {n \choose n - 1} + (-1)^n {n \choose n} = 0,
$$

and, immediately after (in **Exercise 8.5**, (3)), he asks the reader to prove it.

I have no problem coming up with proofs for this expression.  What stumps me is Irving's *hint* to prove it, namely to use the fundamental recurrence

$$
{n \choose r} = {n - 1 \choose r - 1} + {n - 1 \choose r},
$$

for all integers $0 \leq r \leq n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Now, this fundamental recurrence is the subject of **Theorem 8.1**, which appears not long before (p. 117) the alternating sum identity.  IOW, the book has not given much else beyond the fundamental recurrence for the proof.

Therefore, I'm looking for a proof of the alternating sum identity that is based only on the fundamental recurrence.

**NB:** As I said before, I know several *other* proofs of the alternating sum identity.  Therefore, my question is *not* asking for a proof of it, but rather it asks how to use the fundamental recurrence as the basis for such a proof.

Comment: Perhaps it's hinting at a proof by induction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} & = & \binom{n}{0} + (-1)^n\binom{n}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \left(\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k} \right) \\
& = & 1+(-1)^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The last two sums cancel except for the end terms, leaving: 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
& = & 1+(-1)^n + (-1)^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{n-1} - \binom{n-1}{0} \\
& = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is proof 1 of this link, where the "fundamental recurrence" is called "Pascal's Rule": https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n

Quoting their proof (without the details):
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \left({-1}\right)^i \binom n i= \binom n 0 + \sum_{i \mathop = 1}^{n - 1} \left({-1}\right)^i \binom n i + \left({-1}\right)^n \binom n n=\displaystyle \binom n 0 + \sum_{i \mathop = 1}^{n - 1} \left({-1}\right)^i \left({\binom {n - 1} {i - 1} + \binom {n - 1} i}\right) + \left({-1}\right)^n \binom n n=\displaystyle \binom n 0 - \binom {n - 1} 0 + \left({-1}\right)^{n - 1} \binom {n - 1} {n - 1} + \left({-1}\right)^n \binom n n=0$$ as a telescoping series.